# Document length is not equal to buffer

Tags: php, mongodb, buffer, document

I am running into a problem when trying to go through all the documents in one of my collections using a PHP script. The collection has about 500k documents. The database is running Mongo 2.6.9, running on Ubuntu 14.04. I am using this syntax to search the collecton:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.2.2:27017,192.168.2.3:27017/products?replicaSet=preplset");
$products = $mongo->products->content;
$cursor = $products->find();
while($cursor->hasNext() !== false) {
    echo "some information";
}
```

I get the following error message (stack dump):

```
object(MongoCursorException)#24 (8) {
    ["message":protected]=> string(61) "Document length (74 bytes) is not equal to buffer (219 bytes)"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=> int(42)
    ["file":protected]=> string(41) "...script.php"
    ["line":protected]=> int(29)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=> array(6) {
            ["file"]=> string(41) "...value.php"
            ["line"]=> int(29)
            ["function"]=> string(7) "getNext"
            ["class"]=> string(11) "MongoCursor"
            ["type"]=> string(2) "->"
            ["args"]=> array(0) {}
        }
    }
    ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
    ["host":"MongoCursorException":private]=> NULL
}
```

The lengths change. I have seen a dozen different lengths. Each time I run this script, it gets through a different percentage of the collection. Sometimes it throws this exception after 4k documents, sometimes 180k. I'm sure I have changes being made on the collection at all times, it is a production database that is being updated continuously

Comment: For temporary, I'd be happy with a way to catch that exception and handle it. I have it in a try/catch block, but this exception causes my script to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have this problem in the future, I will post what I identified to be the cause of my problem and the steps I took to resolve it.

First of all, in the end restarting my mongodb servers one at a time solved my problem. If you are running a functional replication set, this may be worth trying first (before all the work I outline below).

The problem was created by someone creating an index on the PRIMARY node of our replication set without specifically indicating to create the index "in the background" (this is problematic). Then I created a variety of indexes with the "background" option set (not part of the problem). When I started getting this error message, I removed all of the indexes but they remained in memory (and maybe even in file lock on the PRIMARY --unverified).

To resolve the issue, I took each member (one by one) offline, and brought them  online on another (random) port (so they would not communicate with the set):

```
sudo mongod --port 44444 --dbpath /path/to/mongodb/files/ #default is /data/db
```

(the path was needed because mine is in a non-default location)

Once each server was loaded on its own, I dropped all indexes and recreated only the ones I really wanted (and then re-indexed to make sure they were clean):

```
db.collection.dropIndexes() #this drops all indexes except _id index
db.collection.createIndex( { *indexfield*: 1 } ) #1 or -1 for ASC or DESC
db.collection.reIndex() #probably not necessary
```

I then exited the mongodb service and restarted it under normal circumstances, so that it was part of the replica set again.

These steps should be sufficient to fix the problem, but I discovered that a full reboot of each of the nodes (specifically the PRIMARY) was necessary for my error messages to finally go away. This may be worth trying in the first place.